# Android: vector asset distortion

Tags: android, vector, assets

I created a vector asset in Android Studio that i can see correctly but once i launch my app it gets distorted.

[Original Vector Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk2Nm.png)

[Distorted In App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMqfa.png)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="45dp"
    android:height="79dp"
    android:viewportWidth="45.9"
    android:viewportHeight="79.2">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M22.9,1.5C42.1,1.6 41.7,3 41.7,3s1.2,-1.1 -0.7,-1.9S28.7,0 22.9,0S6.7,0.4 4.8,1.1S4.1,3 4.1,3S3.7,1.6 22.9,1.5"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M22.9,3c19.2,0.1 18.5,1.4 18.5,1.4S41,4.9 42.1,7c1.1,2.2 3.4,6.7 3.4,6.7s-7.6,-1 -22.6,-0.9c-15.2,-0.1 -15,-0.1 -22.6,0.9c0,0 2.4,-4.5 3.4,-6.7c0.2,-0.4 1.6,-1.7 0.7,-2.6C4.4,4.4 3.7,3.1 22.9,3"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M22.9,71.4c22,0 22.9,-1.7 22.9,-1.7l0.1,-54.4c0,0 -7.9,-1.2 -22.9,-1.1C7.9,14.1 0,15.3 0,15.3l0.1,54.4C0.1,69.7 0.9,71.4 22.9,71.4"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M22.9,75.2C10.7,75.2 4.6,74 4.6,74c-4.2,-1.1 -4.5,-2.6 -4.5,-2.6S0.9,73 22.9,73s22.9,-1.7 22.9,-1.7s-0.3,1.5 -4.5,2.6C41.3,74 35.2,75.2 22.9,75.2"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M22.9,79.2c-16.5,0 -16.4,-1.3 -16.4,-1.3l-1.3,-2.1c0,0 5.5,1.3 17.7,1.3s17.7,-1.3 17.7,-1.3l-1.3,2.1C39.3,77.9 39.4,79.2 22.9,79.2"/>
```

I'm using the drawable as  a menu item icon, all icons in the menu are good except for the ic_menu_item which is distorted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_weapon"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_weapon"
            android:title="Weapons" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_item"
            android:title="Items" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the drawable inside of a layout? I've had problems with using "wrap_content" when using non-square vectors. Can you try setting the view dimensions in the layout to match one of the dimensions (width or height), then using "wrap_content" with the other?

Example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/drawable_src"/>
```

Comment: I'm using the drawable in a menu item icon. I added the menu code to the post.